# git rebase after fixing conflict

Tags: git, git-rebase

Sometimes I run into this problem after rebasing and fixing conflict.
I did `git add .` and I would run `git rebase --continue`.

However, I sometimes get this message

```
Applying: xxxxxx
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else  
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.
```

I never understood why this would happen. So, I just end up doing `git rebase --skip` to proceed. Can anybody tell me why Git does not realize that I fixed a conflict?

Answer (score 3):

It's not so much that Git doesn't realize that you've fixed a conflict, as that Git's authors think this is a good safety device.

This happens when the commit you are cherry-picking—remember that `git rebase` is, whether effectively or actually, just a lot of repeated cherry-picking—a change that is *not exactly the same as*, but *very similar to*, a change already in the commits upon which you're rebasing.

For instance, suppose the original work goes like this:

```
...--o--*           <-- origin/develop
         \
          A--B--C   <-- develop
```

Here `A`, `B`, and `C` are three commits that you have made.  Commit `*` is where `develop` was when you first started out, and `origin/develop` still remembers it.

In commit `A`, you fix something in file `a`, and update the `README.txt` file.  In `B`, you fix something in file `b`, but forget to update `README.txt`.  In commit `C` you remember to update `README.txt` so you do that.

Now someone else has made changes and pushed them to your upstream server, so you `git fetch` *their* work:

```
...--o--*--D--E     <-- origin/develop
         \
          A--B--C   <-- develop
```

and then go on to `git rebase` your `develop` upon the new `origin/develop`.  This will, in general *copy* `A`, `B`, and `C` to new commits `A'`, `B'`, and `C'` so that, if all goes well, you will end up with:

```
...--o--*--D--E            <-- origin/develop
         \     \
          \     A'-B'-C'   <-- develop
           \
            A--B--C        [abandoned]
```

The new `A'-B'-C'` commits are simply `git cherry-pick` copies of the originals.

Git is smart enough that if your commit `A` introduces *exactly the same changes* that are also in either `D` or `E`, Git will simply *drop* `A` when copying: it will skip over it and copy just `B` and `C`.  But suppose that either `A` "equals" `D` in this sense, or—let's say for argument sake that this second case is true—`A` is completely separate and gets copied just fine.  But, it's neither `B` *nor* `C` that "equal" `E`, but rather the sum, `B+C`, that "equal" `E`.  That is, you and they made the *same* fixes, but they remembered to fix up `README.txt` in one commit ... and there's some minor spelling difference in their change to file `b`—or perhaps file `b` was reformatted or something, keeping Git from applying your change as-is.

You go in by hand and resolve whatever it is about `b` that Git is complaining about while Git is trying to cherry-pick commit `B` to make `B'`.  Then you `git add` the resolved files.  But now your file `b` exactly matches the upstream `b`.  While this is on purpose—there's nothing to do to file `b` after all—*Git* doesn't know that you have verified that.  Git thinks maybe you just ran `git checkout HEAD -- b` to see what their version was.  This would extract *their* `b` and pretend everything was resolved, and leave you otherwise in the same situation.<sup>1</sup>

So, since this is going to *drop* your commit `B` entirely, Git gives you this warning.  If the correct thing *is* to drop your commit `B` entirely now, you should run `git rebase --skip` after all, and skip your `B`.

Git will now try to apply your `C` to fix `README.txt`.  This will have nothing it needs to do, since they already did that in their commit `D`.  Your Git will once again see that after resolving—perhaps even automatically, this time—the conflict, there is nothing to commit.  Git will wonder if maybe it got this wrong, and make you run `git rebase --skip` to confirm that this is correct.

Once you are done, it turns out that only `A` needed to be copied, and you actually end up with:

```
...--o--*--D--E       <-- origin/develop
         \     \
          \     A'    <-- develop
           \
            A--B--C   [abandoned]
```

but Git wants to be *really sure* that omitting `B` and `C` from the copying is correct, since it's relatively easy to quite literally *forget* to `git add` when running `git rebase --continue`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This may make more sense if you realize that, very early on, Git didn't *have* a good built-in `git cherry-pick` command.  Instead, rebasing turned a commit into a patch, then tried to apply the patch, as if someone had mailed it to you.  Git would then be unable to tell if you'd just forgotten to apply the patch at all.